# Как добавить данные в инпуте с помощью js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет!
Я использую вот [эту](https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable) библиотеку для создания меню.
На данный момент мой html выглядит вот так:

```
<div class="dd" id="nestable">
<ol class="dd-list">
    <li class="dd-item">
        <button data-action="collapse" type="button">Collapse</button>
        <button data-action="expand" type="button" style="display: none;">Expand</button>
        <div class="dd-handle">
            <input class="form-control" required="" data-id="19" disabled="" name="page[18][name]" type="text" value="dwq">
            <input name="page[18][order]" type="hidden">
            <input name="page[18][parent]" type="hidden">
        </div>
        <ol class="dd-list">
            <li class="dd-item">
                <div class="dd-handle">
                    <input class="form-control" required="" disabled="" name="page[19][name]"
                           type="text" value="dwq" data-id="19">
                    <input name="page[19][order]" type="hidden">
                    <input name="page[19][parent]" type="hidden">
                </div>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Для удобства я оставил только одну вложенность.

Как можно в поле `<input name="page[id][order]" type="hidden">` в value поставить порядок в котором этот блок стоит, и для этого поля `<input name="page[id][parent]" type="hidden">` указать в value идентификатор элемента выше?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Что такое "идентификатор элемента выше"?

```js
$('.dd-handle input[type="hidden"][name*="order"]').each(function(idx, el){
  el.value = idx; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dd" id="nestable">
  <ol class="dd-list">
    <li class="dd-item">
      <button data-action="collapse" type="button">Collapse</button>
      <button data-action="expand" type="button" style="display: none;">Expand</button>
      <div class="dd-handle">
        <input class="form-control" required="" data-id="19" disabled="" name="page[18][name]" type="text" value="dwq">
        <input name="page[18][order]" type="hidden">
        <input name="page[18][parent]" type="hidden">
      </div>
      <ol class="dd-list">
        <li class="dd-item">
          <div class="dd-handle">
            <input class="form-control" required="" disabled="" name="page[19][name]" type="text" value="dwq" data-id="19">
            <input name="page[19][order]" type="hidden">
            <input name="page[19][parent]" type="hidden">
          </div>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
```